# Android - Saving state of dynamically changed layout

Tags: android, xml, layout, dynamic, save

I have a layout where users can add buttons and place them where they want. 
I want to allow the user to save their layout so that it is loaded the next time they open the app.
Does anyone know if I can save the file on the sdcard? Alternatively I could use some kind of layout.getXml() method and put it in the database my app uses.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is no file to save when you are generating a layout via code. You will have to create your own file format, which could be saved to the SD card or inserted into a database.

Answer (score 0):

You can us savedInstaceState() method with the same type object as parameter .
there load the ui you want at the time of reloading.
 In onCreate() method put a condition whethere that savedInstaceState obj is null or not . if not then call the LoadUI().

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would create a class holding all the information about this layout and buttons. And write every information of the class to a file with JSONWriter. When the app has opened I just read the file and recreate the arrays using JSONObjects.