# In Android,How to save a "dynamically created layout" and load back when I reopen app?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-xml

When app is running, users adds some views in the `Layout`. I want to store this `Layout`, so that when i reopen the app it should return  the same state.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Use  `onSaveInstanceState()` and  `onRestoreInstanceState()` callbacks to save and restore your views.

[image: basic-lifecycle-savestate]

More at [Managing the Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html) and [Recreating an Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html).

**[EDIT]** - As per @kadatt comment.

I think what you are trying to do is possible duplicate of [android-saving-state-of-dynamically-changed-layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558487/android-saving-state-of-dynamically-changed-layout).

I dont think there is any standard way of doing this. You will have to implement your own functionality to save state of dynamic UI in some form which can be loaded again.

Comment: But i dont want to save views in layout as handling then is hectic since they are dynamic. Is there anyway where layout itself is saved as an XML and restore by one call

Comment: Guys, can u comment/post a simple (java code) example of restoring a view when app is reopened